# php file_get_contents on local file via http

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(file_get_contents("http://localhost/antispam/img.php") == false)
    print 'Error';
else
    print 'Read successfully';

?>
```

This always prints `error`. `img.php` returns a php generated image fine but cannot be read by the above code. My php.ini seems typical and there are no errors shown, what am I missing?

**Note** `allow_url_fopen` has already been set to `On` and `1`

**img.php**

```
$code = 'default';
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$im = @imagecreate(200, 50) or die ("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$bgColour = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$textColour = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

$wSpace = 30; $hSpace = 20;
$prevW = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($code); $i++)
{
    $w = $prevW + rand(20, $wSpace);
    imagestring($im, 5, $w, rand(0,$hSpace),  substr($code, $i, 1), $textColour);
    $prevW = $w;
}

imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: As @raina77ow said, you cannot access via `http` unless `allow_url_fopen` is set. The other option is to access the file via a local file path, something along the lines of `/var/www/antispam/img.php`, or whatever the path is on your server.

Comment: i've already checked my php.ini and everything seems fine. The file is local as in it's in the same dir as the said file, but I understand your point.

Comment: My allow_url_fopen is set to `On` by default.

Comment: @dpk2442: If you access the file via a direct path like that, you'll get the PHP source, not the output of the parsed PHP file.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is a great point, I didn't even think about that.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `file_get_contents("http://localhost/antispam/img.php") === false)...`

Comment: check the status code of your http call.

Comment: It incorrectly results in a positive condition. A tried === then read again into a variable which was still empty.

Comment: @Lee, why is `allow_url_fopen` set to both `On` and `1`?

Comment: Wait, if `=== false` returns `false`, then the function is working, it's just reading nothing from the page. Are you sure `img.php` properly creates the image?

Comment: when it's opened in the browser it's an image object. I assumed the function would read the image binary data.

Comment: @Lee check the http status code.... and set `ini_set('display_errors', on)`

Comment: Copied the code into `img.php`, var_dumped the return of `file_get_contents` - and it's quite a normal binary of JPEG natures. Ok, can you replace `img.php` contents with simple `echo 'something' - to find out the weakest link?

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini: **allow_url_fopen** needs to be activated, for URL opening. 
You don´t need URL Wrapper if the file is on localhost. Just provide the filesystem path.

The file then needs to be readable by the user php is running (normaly apache user when using mod_php, or
the php process in the case of (f)cgi, fpm...)

Comment: I'm running xampplite with apache and `allow_url_fopen` is already set correctly.

Comment: Try it with the path, instead of the URL. The file is located in your document root /antispam/, so you don´t need URL access. Check the file permissions, do a chmod 755 on img.php for testing.

Comment: Why would the OP need to use `file_get_contents` instead of just `require`-ing the local file, how do you think?

Comment: require-ing the image? i don´t know what the op is trying to achieve, but i guess it it not just about checking for file existence. if so, require would also be a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!!!. not only file_get_contents but also wp_remote_get in wordpress